# jQuery autocomplete change source dynamically without if else

Tags: jquery, input, autocomplete

**Inputs:** "Room number", "Name".

Autocomplete source of the second Input is changing depend on the first Input's value.

How can I convert my long "if-else" conditions into the short and simple automatic script?

I tried to do this. Alert is working fine and returns appropriate variable. But it doesn't work for changing Autocomplete source.

Thanks!

```
<input id="First" Placeholder="Room number" />

<input id="Second" Placeholder="Name" />


<script>
var first_input = [
"first",
"second",
"third",
"fourth",
"fifth"
];

$("#First").autocomplete({
source: first_input
})
</script>


<script>
var default_room = [
"Default"
];

var first_room = [
"Glory",
"Dorris",
"Rebecca"
];

var second_room = [
"Will",
"Henry",
"Louie"
];

var third_room = [
"Kraig",
"Eddie",
"Frank"
];

var fourth_room = [
"David",
"Rex",
"Jordan"
];

var fifth_room = [
"Ben",
"Janet",
"Cassaundra"
];


$("#Second").autocomplete({
source: default_room
})


$("#First").on("change blur", function() {

if (this.value == "first") {
$("#Second").autocomplete('option', 'source', first_room)
} else if (this.value == "second") {
$("#Second").autocomplete('option', 'source', second_room)
} else if (this.value == "third") {
$("#Second").autocomplete('option', 'source', third_room)
} else if (this.value == "fourth") {
$("#Second").autocomplete('option', 'source', fourth_room)
} else if (this.value == "fifth") {
$("#Second").autocomplete('option', 'source', fifth_room)
} else {
$("#Second").autocomplete('option', 'source', default_room)
}

/*
var src_change = this.value + "_room";
alert (src_change);
$("#Second").autocomplete('option', 'source', src_change);
*/

})

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple way to do this would be to put the room arrays in to an object which is keyed by the value you expect the `#First` autocomplete to have.

Also note that the `change` or `blur` events will not be raised by selecting an option from the autocomplete; you need to use the `select` property of the configuration object to handle the selection event. Try this:

```js
var rooms = {
  "default": ["Default"],
  "first": ["Glory", "Dorris", "Rebecca"],
  "second": ["Will", "Henry", "Louie"],
  "third": ["Kraig", "Eddie", "Frank"],
  "fourth": ["David", "Rex", "Jordan"],
  "fifth": ["Ben", "Janet", "Cassaundra"]
}

$("#Second").autocomplete({
  source: ["Default"]
})

$("#First").autocomplete({
  source: [
    "first",
    "second",
    "third",
    "fourth",
    "fifth"
  ],
  select: function(e, ui) {
    var room = ui.item.value;
    if (!rooms.hasOwnProperty(room))
      room = 'default';

    $("#Second").autocomplete('option', 'source', rooms[room])
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<input id="First" Placeholder="Room number" />
<input id="Second" Placeholder="Name" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but script is not working.. Maybe I did something wrong. Can you put your code on jsfiddle, if it's not difficult for you?

Comment: The issue is because you're hooking to events which won't be called. I've edited the answer to give you the full example